# StyleConstants Text Background, Alignment Not Working Together

Tags: java, swing, background, alignment, jtextpane

Consider the code,

**Question #1**

```
StyledDocument doc=textPane.getStyledDocument();
SimpleAttributeSet attrib=new SimpleAttributeSet();
attrib.addAttribute(StyleConstants.CharacterConstants.Alignment,StyleConstants.ALIGN_RIGHT);
doc.insertString(0,"This is sample text",attrib);
```

Why am i not able to get the alignment? and why i am able to get it by doing this

```
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength(),attrib,false);
```

**Question #2**

```
attrib.addAttribute(StyleConstants.ColorConstants.Background,Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength(),attrib,false);
```

Why am i not able to get the background color? and why i am able to get it by doing this

```
doc.insertString(0,"This is sample text",attrib);
```

**Question #3**

When can i get both working together i.e. text with a background and right alignment except using this way,

```
doc.insertString(0,"This is sample text",attrib);
doc.setParagraphAttributes(0,doc.getLength(),attrib,false);
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thanks. Updated. Hope that is clear.

Comment: It is clearly not an SSCCE.

Comment: which part of SSCCE is so difficult to understand that you can't provide one ;-)

Comment: I think i have removed the confusing part!

Comment: *"I think i have removed the confusing part!"*  Who's confused?  I mean, *besides* you.  Post an ***SSCCE!***

Answer (score 3):

The issue is mixing paragraph and text attributes. There are two groups of attributes character attributes - font, font size, font color etc. and paragraph attributes like alignment, indents, line spacing, tab stops etc.

Bot the groups are applied to different levels of hierarchy (`Document` structure levels). Character attributes are applied to leaves (text elements) but paragraph attributes are applied to parents of the leaves (paragraph elements).

So `StyledDocument` has 2 methods `setCharacterAttributes` and `setParagrapphAttributes` to apply the attributes to proper level.

Thus when you insert string attributes are applied to leaves so only character attributes has meaning.